# Debugging eclipse console with scanner

Tags: java, console

I am trying to read input from eclipse console with following sample code and sample input. I paste the whole input in console after i run the program.
sample code

```
public class App {
    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner = scanner.useDelimiter("\\n");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String out = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(out);
            // System.exit(0);
        }

        scanner.close();
        System.out.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Sample input:

```
8 5  
2 3 1 2 3 2 3 3  
0 3  
4 6  
6 7  
3 5  
0 7
```

my problem is 
1.) everything is printed except the last line. if i press enter key the last line is printed after a line break not same as input.
2.) was unable exit the loop and terminate JVM. with eclipse luna jre8/jre7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the input didn't had '/n' "next line" for the last input line 0 7 . In Scanner API for next line inputs, each '/n' or line break is a horizon . last line didn't have a horizon. So the "findPatternInBuffer" method matches pattern till the horizon if horizon not found and there is no next line then it waits as if there is more possible input pattern. line 1013-1016 of Scanner class ->

```
// The match may be longer if didn't hit horizon or real end
if (searchLimit != horizonLimit) {
     // Hit an artificial end; try to extend the match
    needinput = true;
```

if you provide an empty next line in the input issue goes away.

Answer (score 1):

1. The last line will only be read once you've pressed enter. I don't think Eclipse even sends the characters to your app otherwise (e.g. you're able to delete what you've typed).
2. [Scanner#hasNextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--) may block. So it will wait for you next input. You may have to provide something like an [EOF character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) to terminate the loop, though I'm not sure if you can type that into the Eclipse console.

As a workaround you can dedicate inputs like 'quit' to exit the loop, or if you did read from a file, then it would always has an EOF.

Comment: 1.) as soon as i press CTRL+V all the input till second lastline gets printed , then enter key brings the last line , 2.) to exit the loop i understand i might require an EOF.